# Unable to access ribbon toolbar in Japanese OS with System.Windows.Automation

Tags: c#, com, microsoft-ui-automation

I tried to access a third party ribbon control in Japanese OS. It is working with the UI Automation COM API. But it is not working with the managed System.Windows.Automation. And it is even not working with COM API, when the managed dll is loaded. Initially I thought that, it is a problem with the win32 client side providers given by the UIAutomationClient.dll. I cleared the ProxyManager ProxyDescriptionTable by invoking the SetProxyDescriptionTable function  before invoking the COM API . Still it is not working.

Everything is working fine in English OS.

I have two questions.

1. What may be the reason for this situation?
2. Is it possible to use the latest UI Automation COM API with the Win32 Client Side providers given by the managed UIAutomationClient.dll?

Comment: Which version of the .NET framework are you using?  Later versions *may* have better interoperation with the native DLLs.  Alternatively, you can try the [UIA COM Wrapper](http://uiacomwrapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I am using .Net 4.0. I have tried UIA COM Wrapper. It is working in Japanese OS for accessing ribbon. 
But it does not support the Win32 Client Side providers given by System.Windows.Automation. 
I need to use this for accessing some old controls. Also when I used it in combination with System.Windows.Automation in the same process, it is not working. 
So as a workaround, I have loaded the UIA COM Wrapper in a separate process as a COM exe server and accessing it from my application.(Only in Japanese OS)
For english OS, I will use the System.Windows.Automation directly.

Comment: Yes, you only get one set of providers.